# Feature Branch Git Reset --hard to Master After Rebasing to Master

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm using Sourcetree as a git GUI instead of running command-line git commands, so I am not sure about the exact parameters being added.

I have `featureBranch` with one commit, I rebase that commit onto `dev` branch (pre-prod)

I then reset --hard `featureBranch` to the latest commit on `dev`

The graph looks like line a single line (`dev` branch) and `featureBranch` is pointing to the latest commit on `dev`

There are two devs working on this project.

The motivation is to keep Merge commits out of the dev branch and to avoid `friendship bracelet` graphs

1. What are the potential downfalls to this approach
2. Will this work with 2+ commits on `featureBranch`

Comment: Having rebased the one commit onto `dev` (so that `featureBranch` is one commit *ahead of* `dev`), you then told Git to *drop* that one commit *off the end of* `featureBranch`. You now have no new commit. That's probably not what you wanted in the first place.

Comment: The branches say they are in sync now since I reset to the commit on `dev`, github commit matches as well (including the latest commit)